# Hartl Ruby on Rails Tutorial Asset Pipeline custom.css.scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm a little confused as to why Hartl creates a new file custom.css.scss instead of using application.css and the stylesheets generated when creating controllers.

A related question is: do all the files in app/assets/stylesheets automatically get included in every view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always best practice to organize your code into separate files. 
Your **application.css** is the file that requires all the css files in your current directory. The file should be structured as such:

```
/* ...
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

Where `require_tree .` requires all the stylesheets in the current directory and `require_self` require its self meaning that you can put your css in this file and it will be included in your application layout. Take a look at the Rails documentation on [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

And to answer you last question, yes by default the stylesheets are automatically included in all your views via `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>` located in the `<head>` section of your `application.html.erb` file

Comment: No problem, if you think that I answered correctly please check my answer as the accepted one.

Comment: So if I create a users controller and a pages controller, users.scss will be included in a view related to the pages controller?

Comment: Well you don't necessarily need to create a users.css. Tell me, what would you do in the users.css file? css files are not specific to controllers. Your asset pipeline is just the "link" between your html in your views and the stylesheets.

Comment: The rails generate controller Users command automatically creates app/assets/stylesheets/users.scss. I was wondering it if it's conventional to put any style specifications related to users views on users.scss file.

Comment: Yes its the convention. A good way to organize your code and workflow.